# Magento 2 : _module.less not being included from custom theme

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom theme (basically a copy of Luma) and am not seeing the _module.less from the module overrides appear in the CSS. I know the module override is working because I can see the template updates, but I don't see CSS/Less updates. I have tried using the grunt tool to compile Less but that has no effect.

I can see my changes in the less files in my theme under pub/static/frontend/ but the compiled css does not contain my changes.

It's probably something stupid but any help is appreciated. I am on Magento 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was due to a node module. Deleting the modules and reinstalling fixed the issue. I also cleared my npm cache just to be sure.